# Simple SVG scaling of a path

Tags: animation, matrix, svg

I currently have the following SVG, and wish to animate the path:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="112.5px" height="115.4px" viewBox="0 0 112.5 115.4" enable-background="new 0 0 112.5 115.4" xml:space="preserve">

    <g>
        <ellipse fill="#333333" cx="56.3" cy="56.3" rx="56.3" ry="56.3"/>
    </g>

    <g>
        <path fill="none"  class="iphone-feature-icon-heart-path" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M82.6,50L82.6,50c-0.2-8.1-6.9-15.2-15.1-15.2
            c-4.8,0-9,2.4-11.8,6c-2.8-3.6-7-6-11.8-6c-8.3,0-15,7.2-15.1,15.2h0c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6
            c0.7,20.5,26.6,29,26.6,29s26.3-8.4,27.1-28.9c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1C82.6,50.1,82.6,50.1,82.6,50z"/>

    </g>
```

A 'pulse' animate along the origin point of the path is what is desired. I've tried dropping this between the last group, however there are a couple of problems with that. First of all, it doesn't animate back to original scale.

```
<animateTransform attributeType="XML"
    attributeName="transform" type="scale"
    from="1 1" to="1.5 1.5"
    begin="0s" dur="2s" fill="freeze"/>
```

Second of all it doesn't scale along the center point of the path. I had thought about using transform-origin 50%, 50% and doing the pulse in css, however this doesn't work in firefox (or at least it doesn't animate along the true origin.)

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y1kdna46/3/

From reading around there appears to be a transform matrix that can be used to do this cross browser. Anyone any tips / advice? As best I can I wish to avoid CSS / javascript to perform this. i.e. do it all within the code of the SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems about right. I've transformed the path so it scales about the origin and used values to do and then undo the scaling. Note also the additive="sum" so I don't overwrite my initial transform.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="112.5px" height="115.4px" viewBox="0 0 112.5 115.4" xml:space="preserve">

  <g>
   <ellipse fill="#333333" cx="56.3" cy="56.3" rx="56.3" ry="56.3"/>
  </g>

  <g transform="translate(50, 50)">
   <path transform="translate(-50, -50)" fill="none"  class="iphone-feature-icon-heart-path" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M82.6,50L82.6,50c-0.2-8.1-6.9-15.2-15.1-15.2
    c-4.8,0-9,2.4-11.8,6c-2.8-3.6-7-6-11.8-6c-8.3,0-15,7.2-15.1,15.2h0c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6
    c0.7,20.5,26.6,29,26.6,29s26.3-8.4,27.1-28.9c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1C82.6,50.1,82.6,50.1,82.6,50z"/>
    <animateTransform attributeType="XML"
        attributeName="transform" type="scale"
            values="1;1.5;1" additive="sum"
        begin="0s" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </g>


</svg>
```

Comment: Legend. Worked a treat.